# Open form to view related records if they exist or open blank form otherwise

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi I have a form called frmGeneralInformation where the main data is inputted about a book. Then I want a button that opens a form called frmFolio which shows the information about each page in the book. If records about the folios of the book already exist, the existing records should be shown with the option to add more folios. Otherwise a blank frmFolio should be created.

This is my VB code:

```
Private Sub FolioForm_Click()


Dim Found As Boolean
Found = Not IsNull(DLookup("SurveyID", "tblGenInfo_Folio", "SurveyID = " & .SurveyID))

If Found = True Then

    Dim recordID As Integer
    recordID = Me.FolioID
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmFolio", , , "FolioID = " & FolioID

Else
     DoCmd.OpenForm "frmFolio"

End Sub
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Invalid or unqualified error
```

This is the relationship between the tables:

[image]

Comment: Missing `Me` qualifier in front of `.Survey`. Your relationship design allows a folio to be associated with multiple surveys. Is that correct? Quite possibly junction table is not needed. The Else code will just open form with all records. Use the acFormAdd parameter. But should not need the Else code. If there is no match to criteria, form should just open to new record row.

Comment: Why not use form/subform arrangement?